# React first value?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

```
{movie.episode_run_time && <span> {movie.episode_run_time} min. |</span>}
```

Having done this, I get an array of time 40 60 45 32 min. , how can I get only the first value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{movie.episode_run_time && <span> {movie.episode_run_time[0]} min. |</span>}
```

Comment: Thanks!Great is work! 
And do not say how to get a value equal to a certain value, for example, US?